# Can I use pressure-treated lumber to reinforce a bridge?

Tags: construction

I am re-decking a wooden bridge. I need to add a support beam. Can this be done using 2 x 10 pressure treated wood. The bridge length is 24 feet. The beam will need to be the same.

Comment: Length is only one factor. How wide is the bridge? Is it supported only at the very ends (24 feet apart) or are the supports closer together? What goes over the bridge - people? bicycles? cars? trucks? What are the dimensions of the existing frame & deck boards? etc.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a LOT more information before we can help you; please edit a diagram and whatever else you can think of into your question.

Comment: I would recommend taking a picture with your smartphone and uploading it. It helps give context for people to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer to any home improvement question is 'it depends'. In general, yes, you can use a 2x10 or rather a number of them to make a 'built-up beam' for supporting a load but you may be better off using a pressure treated Parallel Strand Lumber (PSL) beam. You can find more information and a load chart here:

http://www.nbslumber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/PSL-SPEC-SHEETS-1.pdf